# In Xcode 4.1, how to change the name of 'New Group'?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

When I add a 'New Group' to a project with Xcode 4.1, I can not change the name of the group. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select the group and press enter, then type your new name.

Clicking twice ***slowly*** also works.

Comment: You won't find it in the Ctrl-Click menu, that's for sure.

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if a new group would automatically change into edit mode (as Finder does with *New Folder*) as you'd rarely keep the default name..

Comment: I'm sure it used to, seems they introduced a bug at some point.

Answer (score 1):

It works the same way as files and directories in Finder. First select the group, then hit your carriage return key. You can then edit the group name.